# Calling malloc in structure

Tags: c

```
struct NODE{
double theta, phi;
int ID;
int pointer;
};

int main(void)
{
FILE *fp;           

int  ID[5000][5000];
struct NODE node[5000*5000];    
struct NODE node2[5000*5000];
int elem[5000][8];      
int tempID;
for(i=0; i< 5000*5000; i++){
    node[i].theta = 0;
    node[i].phi   = 0;
}
for(k=0; k<5000; k++){
    for(j=0; j< 5000; j++){
        ID[k][j] = -1;
    }
}
}
```

This is a part of the source code of my project. here i want to allocate memory in this lines using malloc. How can i do this??

```
struct NODE node[5000*5000];    
struct NODE node2[5000*5000];
```

Comment: `malloc(5000 * 5000 * sizeof(struct NODE));`

Comment: Please note that on some systems that code in main will crash  the reason is that the function stack cannot be that huge :) int  ID[5000][5000];

Comment: If you don't particularly want to allocate the storage dynamically, you can avoid the stack size limitations by moving the variable declarations to the static data area just *before* `main`.

Comment: You are using unwieldly large data structures. In general that means something is wrong with your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `malloc` in the following manner:

```
struct NODE *node, *node2;
node = malloc(5000*5000*sizeof(*node));
if (node == NULL)
{
   exit(1);  // or any other error check 
}
node2 = malloc(5000*5000*sizeof(*node));
if (node2 == NULL)
{
   exit(1);  // or any other error check 
}
```

Rest of the code will be unchanged.

Comment: `sizeof(node)` ==> `sizeof(*node)`

Comment: `node = malloc(5000 * 5000 * sizeof (*node));`. You want the size of the struct, not the pointer.

Comment: Please free your node1 pointer if node2 allocation fail. Takes time to get used to good habits